# "Jupyter lab build" fails on corporate network

Tags: conda, jupyter-lab

I use jupyterlab (2.2.6) on windows, which is installed with conda.

I work for a company that uses Zscaler for internet access security, so for conda and other less-native windows applications I have to ensure the ssl library trusts the zscaler proxy.

For a plain installation of jupyterlab with conda "jupyter lab build" always fails

My workaround is to locate .yarnrc, usually in \Miniconda3\envs\dev2\Lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\staging.yarnrc and add "strict-ssl false" or point to a bundle of certificates.

Yarn is being used by jupyterlab and as the workaround works, I expect the reason "jupyter lab build" failing is that the embedded yarn misses the required ssl configuration.

My question now is, if there is a better way to configure yarn in jupyterlab.

Br,
Per